# How can I redirect to the attached href in html via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redirect

I want to redirect my website to the attached href thats in the  code by jQuery. Because I first want to have an animation playing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.preload').addClass('preload-loading')
        setTimeout(function(){

            url = location.href;
         $( location ).attr("href", url); <<-- I WANT TO REDIRECT TO THE PAGE THATS IN THE HREF IN THE HTML

        }, 500);

  });
});
```

Comment: What is `location` in `$( location )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

- See below code may be, its help to you

  `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.preload').addClass('preload-loading')

      setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = url; // REDIRECT 
      }, 500);

    });
  });`